# i want to create a dynamic dropdown (NOT WITH oci/mysql)

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

i want to create a dynamic dropdown 
showing SDE when DE is selected 
My problem is that though the list of DE is displayed (snapshot attached) 
but i don't get SDE 
(As i think that I am unable to pass the onclick value 
following line in code:--------- 
echo ''.$jto.'';)

I have tried a lot of options but none worked

```
    enter code here

    <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td> select de</td>
<td><select id="dedd" onChange="change_de()">
<option>select</option>
<?php


    $jtosql="SELECT DISTINCT DE_OD FROM cdr_phone_control";
    $jtoqr=odbc_exec($conn, $jtosql);
    while(odbc_fetch_row($jtoqr))
                { 
            $jto=odbc_result($jtoqr,"DE_OD");

            echo '<option value="'.$jto.'">'.$jto.'</option>';
            //echo "<option>".$jto."</option>";
            /*?><option value="<?php echo $jto; ?>">"<?php".$jto."?></option><?php
            ?><option><?php echo ."$jto." ?></option><?php
            ?><option value="<?php echo $jto ?>"><?php echo "$jto"; ?></option><?php
            ?><a href="test52.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>" style="text-decoration:none"><input type="submit" value="<?php echo $b." "; ?>"</a><?php*/
            }           
$page=$_GET["dedd"];            
            ECHO $jto;
        echo $jtoqr;
        echo $page;
    /*?><a href="test52.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>" style="text-decoration:none"><input type="submit" value="<?php echo $b." "; ?>"</a><?php*/       
?>
</select>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>select sde</td>
<td>
<div id="sde">
<select><option>select</option></select></div>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_de()
{
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?de="+document.getElementById("dedd").value,false); 
xmlhttp.send(null);
//alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("sde").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
</script>

/*AJAX.PHP STARTS HERE */
$de=$_GET['dedd'];
//$staff=$_POST['callLL'];
if($de!="")
{
$jtosql="SELECT DISTINCT SDO_OD FROM cdr_phone_control where de_od='$de'";
    $jtoqr=odbc_exec($conn, $jtosql);
    echo "<select>";
    while(odbc_fetch_row($jtoqr))
                { 
            $jto=odbc_result($jtoqr,"SDO_OD");
            //echo "<option>".$jto."</option>";
            /*?><option value="<?php echo $jto; ?>">"<?php".$jto."?></option><?php
            ?><option><?php echo ."$jto." ?></option><?php*/
            ?><option value="<?php echo $jto ?>"><?php echo "$jto"; ?></option><?php
            }
echo "</select>";   

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S37R8.jpg
```

Comment: There is a lot of mistakes in your code.You should change the way of writing the code.Then you are getting any error?

Comment: When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?  What is the resulting HTML?  Is the JavaScript change handler invoked?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: you should not give any echo or print in the select tag

Comment: those echo are just to see if i get desired output .

Comment: yes i am getting first dropdown, without any error, but when I select any one of those options i get NOTHING,                                                echo '<option value="'.$jto.'">'.$jto.'</option>'; THIS IS MAIN CAUSE. OF THE PROBLEM, HOW TO PUSH THE SELECTED VALUE AS INPUT OUT OF THESE OPTIONS TO EXECUTE MY SECOND QUERY? AJAX, JAVA RESPONSE IS OK if($de!="") condition is met & second dropdown hides, have attached snapshot